# How to structure my main pygame while loop?

Tags: python, pygame

For my pygame Tower Defence program, I have a python file called `main.py` that creates an instance of a class called `Menu` (which is in a separate module called `startup.py`
) that initiates the main menu of my game.

A button on the menu screen then runs (when clicked) a function called `main` in a different python module called `mapgen.py`. This function contains all the necessary code to run the main game and update the screen. It creates instances for the necessary classes and then in a while loop, runs all class functions:

```
def main():
    global money
    money = side.Money()
    global health
    health = side.Health()
    global live_grid
    live_grid = Grid() #Creates instance of grid
    global live_sidebar
    live_sidebar = side.Sidebar() #Creates instance of sidebar
    while True:
        money.money_update() #Updates the current money of the player
        live_grid.blit_grid() #Blits the grid background
        live_sidebar.event_main() #Runs event handler for the sidebar to update any information there
        live_sidebar.blit_sidebar() #Blits the sidebar
        pg.display.update()
        C.clock.tick(C.FPS)
```

The reason I have the `main` (the main game loop) as a function is so i can call it from the `startup` module (that contains the main menu).

However, this prevents me from making a pause screen as i can't resume the function without initiating the classes again.

I also need to be able to access the instances of the classes from other modules too. This is why i make the instances global for the module.

If i try to create the instances of the classes outside of the function to avoid this, i get errors that i believe are caused due to the way python imports modules, like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import startup, config as C
  File "C:\Users\bobsh\Programming Project\Version 0.7b\startup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import config as C, button as B, mapgen
  File "C:\Users\bobsh\Programming Project\Version 0.7b\button.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mapgen, config as C, startup
  File "C:\Users\bobsh\Programming Project\Version 0.7b\mapgen.py", line 140, in <module>
    font = B.font
AttributeError: module 'button' has no attribute 'font' (even though it does)
```

This a pretty long stretch of a question, but how should i structure my while loop and subsequently any other code so that i am able to easily create a pause screen (essentially interrupt the main game process so the player can choose whether to quit or resume) and also run the game from the `Menu` class in `startup.py`?

Here's a Github [gist](https://gist.github.com/bobshaniqua/01a132d76fe86a0c38c859c5907e4e3d) of my code, and here is a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home/Version%200.7b) of everything required to run the game itself.

I'd thoroughly appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: I can easily comment on this because I answered your other question, which means I read all of your code. To be honest, I don't see the need of structuring your code around the `startup` module. It just seems unnecessary to go through all of this structural architecture just for one line of code to be ran in a separate file. Do you have any specific reason for structuring your code this way? It seems to only be causing a hassle, to my eyes.

Comment: Ultimately i think it comes down to inexperience. I realise now that a main game loop would be the best method of structuring my program, I'm just not entirely sure how i'd restructure my code to do that.

Comment: I'll do my best to answer this question without actually running the game because the Dropbox link doesn't work: it is not a share link. If you could give a share link of the game, that'd be great! Thanks!

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer My bad. I can edit the link in a couple of hours time. Ill let you know when.

Comment: Also, I see in the error message that you have the line `font = B.font` which should be `font = B.font()` because `font()` is a function and you are calling it.

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer That error happens when i instance the classes outside the function. The line that produces that error is the exact same line from somewhere else which works 100%. Its due to all the modules importing each other. The code in the current gist works but i want to organise it so that it runs from one central main game loop with a main menu.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will have two parts, one showing you how to hack a pause screen into your `main()` function, the other giving you an outline of how you could structure your code a little better.

**Hacking a pause screen into your `main()` function:**

Alright, this is by no means the best way of doing it but I don't think it's a bad way of doing it either. It's incredibly simple.

```
#main game function
def main():
    #Creates instances of necessary classes
    global money
    money = side.Money()
    global health
    health = side.Health()
    global live_grid
    live_grid = Grid()
    global live_sidebar
    live_sidebar = side.Sidebar()

    paused = False

    while True:
        # Pause functionality
        keys = pg.keys.get_pressed();
        if keys[pg.k_SPACE]:
            if paused:
                paused = False 
            else:
                paused = True 


        if not paused:
            money.money_update() #Updates the current money of the player
            live_grid.blit_grid() #Blits the grid background
            live_sidebar.event_main() #Runs event handler for the sidebar to update any information there
            live_sidebar.blit_sidebar() #Blits the sidebar
            pg.display.update()

        if paused:
            # Pause menu code goes here 


        C.clock.tick(C.FPS)
```

That's pretty much it. I've used this technique a lot to overlay different menus, buttons, etc, onto the main game screen and it works good enough. For something simple like a pause screen, I don't think there is any point in creating another class or function, because then you must re-initialize the classes, make sure you are in the same place in the game, etc.

**Structuring your code in a better way:**

Your game is a victim of what I like to call *"the domino effect"*. This term is pretty self-explanatory. You call one function, and that calls another, and so on.

This can all be cured by taking out the lines that are creating this domino effect, and instead, call that function in the file that actually executes the game: `main.py`.

I'll take the first example to show you how you can do this.

```
class Menu():
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = C.screen
        self.button_x = C.game_screen_full_w * 0.4
        self.button_y = [C.game_screen_h * 0.30, C.game_screen_h * 0.50, C.game_screen_h * 0.70]
        self.play_button = B.Button("mapgen.main()", (140, 40), (self.button_x,self.button_y[0]), C.L_BLUE, C.BLUE, None, C.DARK_GREY, C.L_BLUE , "Play")
        self.lead_button = B.Button("startup.Lead()", (200, 40), (self.button_x - 30,self.button_y[1]), C.L_BLUE, C.BLUE, None, C.DARK_GREY, C.L_BLUE, "Leaderboard")
        self.quit_button = B.Button("quit()", (140, 40), (self.button_x,self.button_y[2]), C.L_BLUE, C.BLUE, None, C.DARK_GREY, C.L_BLUE, "Quit")
        self.vol_button = B.Button(None, (50,50), (40,40), C.L_BLUE, C.BLUE, None, C.DARK_GREY, C.L_BLUE, "♫")
        #self.menu_screen()
```

Notice that I commented out the last line. This line calls another function that has a `while` loop in there. As you can see, this creates a domino effect.

Now in `main.py` you can add in the line yourself.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    live_menu = startup.Menu()
    live_menu.menu_screen()
```

The next example I see is the line `if event.button == 1 and self.action is not None: exec(self.action)`. Revise the button code so that it doesn't call the function. Hint: You could return a value instead and use that to call the function from somewhere like `main.py`.

As for importing modules, there is no issue that I see. When you are importing the modules, no code is being ran because you are only defining classes and functions. You got the error that you posted because there are no brackets after `font`. The line should be `font = B.font()`.

*However, you are right when you say that you cannot instantiate the classes outside the function.* You can't because then when you import the file, you are running that line of code. If you wanted you could put that code into it's own function too and call that only once.

Once you have done that, then your code should be a little better structured.

As a rule of thumb for structuring your code when you start out: *Only instantiate classes in **one file**; only create **functions** in one file, not methods, **functions**; try to **limit the domino effect** as much as possible so that your code is as manageable as possible.*

If you need any guidance, have a look at the code in [this repo](https://github.com/PythonProgramming/pygame-tutorial-series). All code is just in one file.

Good luck! I hoped this answer helped you and if you have any more issues, feel free to leave a comment below!

Comment: Thanks for the thought out response! I'll implement your ideas and get back to you.

This should be a share link to the dropbox. If it's not then i have no idea why. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gmu9w8wmm5gokhv/AADPgWCp9eUpER8NMdC4Y8DZa?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the Dropbox link! I'll be sure to have a look. If you have any issues implementing the ideas above, feel free to post a comment!